# DRF: customize PrimaryRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

DRF renders a foreign key with `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` by default and it is represented as a single `pk`.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   bar = models.ForeignKey('Bar')

def FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = [
      'id',
      'bar'
    ]
```

`FooSerializer(foo_instance).data` looks like

```
{ 
  'id': 3,
  'bar': 5,
}
```

I'd like it to become

```
{ 
  'id': 3,
  'bar': {
    'id': 5
  },
}
```

Not just for Foo/Bar, but for whole project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can do it like this:

First, overidde the [**`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f0dbf0a264677f2a53faab402ff49f442fc4383a/rest_framework/relations.py#L238):

```
class DictPrimaryKeyRelatedField(PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        pk = super(DictPrimaryKeyRelatedField, self).to_representation(value)
        return dict(id=pk)
```

Then create a `ModelSerializer`, and override the [**`serializer_related_field`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f0dbf0a264677f2a53faab402ff49f442fc4383a/rest_framework/serializers.py#L882):

```
class CustomModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serializer_related_field = DictPrimaryKeyRelatedField
```

Then use `CustomModelSerializer` in all serializers instead of `ModelSerializer`.

Comment: unless there's a setting to override this, I guess this is the best I could do